# Problems with Async NSURLSession calls in Playground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlsession, swift-playground

I'm trying to implement a custom Google search in IOS.  For testing, I'm trying to test the request in a Playground.  My search URL works fine in the browser (chrome), however in the playground the completion block isn't firing and I'm getting this in the console:  (even after restarting Xcode)

```
2016-02-01 17:00:07.059 GooglePlayground[23603:5654691] 
Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=
/var/folders/1q/fvvgmbxd7zvbl2s0d307pb8m0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.GooglePlayground-8B924AAB-7245-42E2-8771-B5E36703E579/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.GooglePlayground-8B924AAB-7245-42E2-8771-B5E36703E579. 
Errno:1
```

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true



let SearchEngineID = "XXXXX"
let APIKey = "XXXXX"
let searchText = "steelers"
let googleURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=" + searchText + "&key=" + APIKey + "&cx=" + PinCheckSearchEngineID

var nsURL = NSURL(string: googleURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    print("data = \(data)")
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Why would you use playground for testing asynchronous methods?

Comment: I always like to test out code before I incorporate it into an app?

Comment: Create a sample project to test it

Comment: This code works for me in a Playground when giving correct API keys. Print the response and the error to get more details about your specific issue. There's no reason for async stuff to not work in a Playground, I do it on a daily basis.

Comment: I appreciate you checking that...it must be an Xcode bug then, the error message in my question seems to be a common bug when doing async stuff in a playground

Comment: @LeoDabus Why not?